# Is it possible to change the member function pointer from std::bind to lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, std-function, stdbind

I coded callback method with  `std::function`,  `std::bind`.

`std::function` object  `func1` in class A point to function  `bFoo(int, int)` which is member of class B.

My callback code in my program:

```
// Class A - A.h
class A
{
  public:
    template<class T>
    void setCallback(T *pClass, void(T::*pFunc)(int, int));

  private:
    std::function<void(int, int)> func1;
}

template<class T>
inline void A::setCallback(T *pClass, void(T::*pFunc)(int, int))
{
  func1 = std::bind(pFunc, pClass, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2); 
}

// Class A - A.cpp
...
func1(x,y);
...

// Class B - B.h
class B
{
  public:
    void bFoo(int x, int y);

  private:
    A a; // instance of class A
}

// Class B - B.cpp
B::B()
{
  a.setCallback(this, &B::bFoo);
}
```

It works fine.

However, I heard that in C++ 14 and higher, `std::bind` can be completely replaced by lambda, and lambda has many advantages over `std::bind`.

So I tried to change the bind to lambda and looked up many examples, but in my case I haven't found how to replace bind to lambda.

I want to assign a member function from another class into `std::function` using lambda, not `std::bind`.

is this possible?

Comment: It should simply be `[=](int x, int y){(pClass->*pFunc)(x,y);}`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You're right. Thanks to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to do it with your current code by using

```
func1 = [=](int x, int y){ (pClass->*pFunc)(x,y); };
```

In my opinion it's probably better to write out the lambda at the calling site instead.
To do that you need to modify `setCallback`.

```
class A
{
  public:
    template<class T>
    void setCallback(T callback);

  private:
    std::function<void(int, int)> func1;
}

template<class T>
inline void A::setCallback(T callback)
{
  func1 = callback; 
}
```

Then we can call from `B`s constructor with a lambda.

```
class B
{
  public:
    void bFoo(int x, int y);

  private:
    A a; // instance of class A
}

// Class B - B.cpp
B::B()
{
  a.setCallback([&](int x, int y){ bFoo(x, y); }); // & will capture this
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In brief,

```
struct A {
    using Callback = std::function<void(int, int)>;
    void setCallback(Callback cb) { func1 = std::move(cb); }
};
B::B() { a.SetCallback([this](int x, int y) { bFoo(x, y); }); }
```

You should capture `this` to bind a method to an object.

There should be nothing wrong with `std::bind`, unless you work for one well-known company that has its own peculiar notion of having its own peculiar notions.

Comment: The Secretive Fruit Company, or the Not Invented Here So We Pretend It Doesn't Exist Company?

Comment: No, the one that does not use exceptions because they are so dangerous and unreasonable that manual error checking and rethrowing is definitely much safer. They have even created their own language where a typical function call looks like `if _, err := F(); err != nil {` — because doing everything manually and very verbosely gives you a better feeling of control, you know.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I can guess the company in the very third guess (since my first two guesses were a swing-and-a-miss), even if you allowed me 1e+100 guesses.